# How to test an async database transaction implemented by Elixir.Task?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I am trying to insert a record in database asynchronously using `Elixir.Task` in a Phoenix controller. 
The test that covers that controller method, log an exception that DB connection error (**DBConnection.OwnershipError**).

I tried to set the controller test as async so Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox mode would be shared.

Link to controller Task implementation: [link](https://github.com/hasanloo/url_shortener/blob/704a30173371f62c998701a853e8649eb6225c0f/lib/url_shortner_web/controllers/link_controller.ex#L42)

Link to the test for controller: [link](https://github.com/hasanloo/url_shortener/blob/master/test/url_shortener_web/controllers/link_controller_test.exs)

Log:

```
05:28:21.325 [error] Task #PID<0.438.0> started from #PID<0.436.0> terminating
** (DBConnection.OwnershipError) cannot find ownership process for #PID<0.438.0>.

When using ownership, you must manage connections in one
of the four ways:

* By explicitly checking out a connection
* By explicitly allowing a spawned process
* By running the pool in shared mode
* By using :caller option with allowed process

The first two options require every new process to explicitly
check a connection out or be allowed by calling checkout or
allow respectively.

The third option requires a {:shared, pid} mode to be set.
If using shared mode in tests, make sure your tests are not
async.

The fourth option requires [caller: pid] to be used when
checking out a connection from the pool. The caller process
should already be allowed on a connection.

If you are reading this error, it means you have not done one
of the steps above or that the owner process has crashed.

See Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox docs for more information.
    (ecto_sql) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:618: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.raise_sql_call_error/1
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:649: Ecto.Repo.Schema.apply/4
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:262: anonymous fn/15 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.do_insert/4
    (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:90: Task.Supervised.invoke_mfa/2
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Function: #Function<4.97600206/0 in UrlShortenerWeb.LinkController.redirect_url/2>
    Args: []
05:28:21.380 [error] Task #PID<0.435.0> started from #PID<0.433.0> terminating
** (stop) exited in: DBConnection.Holder.checkout(#PID<0.434.0>, [log: #Function<11.104730475/1 in Ecto.Adapters.SQL.with_log/3>, cache_statement: "ecto_insert_visits", timeout: 15000, pool_size: 10, pool: DBConnection.Ownership])
    ** (EXIT) no process: the process is not alive or there's no process currently associated with the given name, possibly because its application isn't started
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/holder.ex:71: DBConnection.Holder.checkout/2
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:1030: DBConnection.checkout/3
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:1340: DBConnection.run/6
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:540: DBConnection.parsed_prepare_execute/5
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:533: DBConnection.prepare_execute/4
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex.ex:196: Postgrex.query/4
    (ecto_sql) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:658: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.struct/10
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:649: Ecto.Repo.Schema.apply/4
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:262: anonymous fn/15 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.do_insert/4
    (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:90: Task.Supervised.invoke_mfa/2
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Function: #Function<4.97600206/0 in UrlShortenerWeb.LinkController.redirect_url/2>
    Args: []
05:28:21.380 [error] Task #PID<0.441.0> started from #PID<0.439.0> terminating
** (stop) exited in: DBConnection.Holder.checkout(#PID<0.440.0>, [log: #Function<11.104730475/1 in Ecto.Adapters.SQL.with_log/3>, cache_statement: "ecto_insert_visits", timeout: 15000, pool_size: 10, pool: DBConnection.Ownership])
    ** (EXIT) shutdown: "owner #PID<0.439.0> exited"
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/holder.ex:71: DBConnection.Holder.checkout/2
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:1030: DBConnection.checkout/3
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:1340: DBConnection.run/6
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:540: DBConnection.parsed_prepare_execute/5
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:533: DBConnection.prepare_execute/4
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex.ex:196: Postgrex.query/4
    (ecto_sql) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:658: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.struct/10
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:649: Ecto.Repo.Schema.apply/4
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:262: anonymous fn/15 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.do_insert/4
    (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:90: Task.Supervised.invoke_mfa/2
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Function: #Function<4.97600206/0 in UrlShortenerWeb.LinkController.redirect_url/2>
    Args: []
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add tag in use string in test

```
use UrlShortenerWeb.ConnCase, async: false
```

This will run [this line in test case](https://github.com/hasanloo/url_shortener/blob/master/test/support/conn_case.ex#L32), which will provide ownership to db connection for all processes, also test will run synchronously.

Another, more complicated method - to use manual mode and allow the process to use connection.
[This post](https://medium.com/@qertoip/making-sense-of-ecto-2-sql-sandbox-and-connection-ownership-modes-b45c5337c6b7) have a very good explanation about ownership modes

Comment: Setting `Aync` tag as false didn't fix it.

I didn't want to go with manual mode as the article doesn't recommend it as well.

Comment: Error with tag is same?

Comment: Yes, it is the same.

Comment: Maybe task does not have enough time to finish request, try to add `Process.sleep(1000)` in test. Best way is to send some messages from task and `assert_receive` them in test, to be sure that task finished, but sleep is ok too

Comment: Generally, I don't think it is a good idea to add sleep in the tests, it makes tests last long and non-predictable.

Comment: What I did, in this case, was to separate the task, inject it base on ENV and mock it in the test env not to insert into the database.